# PHP's filter_var() Function Generating Warning

Tags: php

Does any body know why the filter_var() function below is generating the warning? Is there a limit on how many characters can be in a character class?

```
$regex = "/^[\w\041\042\043\044\045\046\047\050\051\052\053\054\055\056\057\072\073\074\075\076\077\100\133\134\135\136\140\173\174\175\176]*$/";

$string = "abc";

if(!filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options" => array("regexp"=>$regex))))
{
    echo "dirty";
}

else
{
    echo "clean";
}
```

Warning: filter_var() [function.filter-var]: Unknown modifier ':'

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is interpreted by PHP as this string :

```
string '/^[\w!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~]*$/' (length=40)
```

*(use [`var_dump`](http://www.php.net/var_dump) on $regex, and you'll get that)*

Right in the middle of your regex, so, there is a slash ; as you are using a slash to delimit the regex *(it's the first character of `$regex`)*, PHP thinks this slash in the middle is marking the end of the regex.

So, PHP thinks your regex is actually :

```
/^[\w!"#$%&'()*+,-./
```

Every character that comes after the ending slash are interpreted as [modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

And ':' is not a valid modifier.

You might want to escape the slash in the middle of the regex ;-)

As well as some other characters, btw...

A solution for that might be to use the [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) function.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works now as I added backslashes using it's ASII code "134". I'll put the current regex in another answer right below.

Comment: You're welcome :-) One question comes to my mind, though : why are you using ASCII codes, and not the characters directly ? It would be easier to understand your regex, that way, don't you think ?

Comment: I did think about that for about three seconds earlier, lol! The answer is that I used the space character's ANCII code in a regex before and since then the back of mind my tells me to do it for special characters. I'll likely change my way some day : )

Comment: OK ^^ I understand a bit better, now ^^

Answer (score 0):

Here is the current working regex:

```
/^[\w\041\042\043\044\045\046\047\050\051\052\053\054\134\055\056\134\057\072\073\074\075\076\077\100\133\134\134\134\135\134\136\140\173\174\175\176]*$/i
```